# Cross-platform sound function

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there a Python module that allows me to generate tones (of specified frequency and duration) and that works across all platforms?

My applications runs on both Windows and Raspbian, and I would like something that works using common code.